# Drag and Drop a div without cloning

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help. I think this is very simple but I could not figure out how to do it.

I've successfully created draggable elements and they are working perfectly as expected. I can drag and drop them without any errors.

The problem is this:

While I'm dragging (not yet dropping it) a box (which is a div), I have two copies of that box on my screen: one is the box on its original position, and the other is the box that drags along with my mouse.

What I want to achieve is this:

I want the original box to disappear as soon as I start dragging. The only box that I want to appear on the screen is the one that drags along with my mouse.

I'm using CodeIgniter as my framework, then javascript for my drag and drop effects. I'm not using jquery because I have very limited knowledge of it.

Thanks.

Comment: depends entirely on the js you use, but are not showing us. note the jquery UI works as you describe out of the box.

Comment: the use of php and/or codeigniter is irrelevant to the issue of dragging and dropping elements in a browser, tags removed

Answer (score 1):

Why do this need to use clone, I can't understand.I have write a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wbb123yu/atAMU/) on the jsfiddle with native javascript that maybe U need.

```
ZxDrugProto._druging = function(e) {
    this.top = e.clientY - this.preY + this.top;
    this.left = e.clientX - this.preX + this.left;
    this.dom.style.top = this.top+'px';
    this.dom.style.left = this.left+'px';
    this.preY = e.clientY;
    this.preX = e.clientX;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, I can no longer view your JSFiddle demo.

Comment: [new address](http://jsfiddle.net/zxbing0066/atAMU/)

My Fiddle username had changed long ago, sorry.